# Android AchartEngine: customising graph?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I have created a graph with `AchartEngine` and want to make the following alterations:

1.Move `Y-Axis Title ( called Values)` to the left so that it is off the graph area
2.Increase Size of legend and move it down away from the graph
3.Increase thickness of lines on graph

How can I do so?

Below shows the code relating to my `single and multiple Renderers`:

```
//declaring the Multiple series dataset that the single data sets are added to
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset= new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        //adding multiple series 
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);
        dataset.addSeries(series3);


        //renderer that changes the look etc of the first line (score)
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer= new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);//set line colour
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        //renderer that changes the look etc of the second line (score)
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2= new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setColor(Color.WHITE);//set line colour
        renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

        // renderer that changes the look etc of the second line (score)
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer3.setColor(Color.RED);// set line colour
        renderer3.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer3.setFillPoints(true);


        //Only related to the display of the graphs x and y values
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float val = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18, metrics);


        //renderer that changes the look etc of the overall graph
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multRenderer= new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        //adding single to multiple
        multRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        multRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
        multRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);
        multRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        multRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        multRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(val);
        multRenderer.setChartTitle("");
        multRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(40);
        multRenderer.setXTitle("Games");
        multRenderer.setYTitle("Value"); 
        //setting size of text for labels, legend etc
        multRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(12); 
        multRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        multRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(val);

        //creating the intent
        Intent intent= ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, multRenderer, "Summary Graph");
```

`Screenshot` of Current Graph (note the y-axis and legend don't look correct) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the size and location of the `Legend` by doing the following:

```
multRenderer.setLegendHeight(50);
multRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20;
```

And the location of the Y-axis title (and x) by doing:

```
multRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
```

As far as I know there is no way to increase graph line size, but I may be incorrect.